# MS SQL. Как вывести список из одной таблицы и количество записей связанных сделанных для каждой строки из этого списка в другой таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как из таблиц

```
       | iduser  | idbook
_______|_________|__________

1      |33       |    15
2      |33       |    16
3      |32       |    14


       | iduser  |   name
_______|_________|__________

1      |32       |   name1   
2      |33       |   name2 
3      |37       |   name3
```

Вывести такой результат:

```
       | iduser  |   name   | books quantity
_______|_________|__________|_______________

1      |32       |   name1  |       1
2      |33       |   name2  |       2
```

Comment: Добавьте схему таблиц, пример данных, ожидаемый результат, свой запрос, который не работает/неправильно работает. Иначе скорее всего вопрос будет удален

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. названия таблиц вы не указали, пришлось придумать самому.

```
CREATE TABLE #Books (iduser int, idbook int)

INSERT #Books VALUES (33,15),(33,16),(32,14)

CREATE TABLE #Users (iduser int, name nvarchar(50))

INSERT #Users VALUES (32,'a'),(33,'b'),(37,'f')
```

-- Запрос который вам нужен:

```
SELECT u.iduser, u.name, COUNT(b.idbook) CntBooks 
FROM #Users u
LEFT JOIN #Books b on u.iduser = b.iduser
GROUP BY u.iduser, u.name
```

-- если не хотите чтобы выводились юзеры с нулевым количеством книг добавьте
`WHERE isnull(b.idbook,0) > 0` перед `GROUP BY`
или `HAVING COUNT(b.idbook) > 0` после `GROUP BY`

```
DROP TABLE #Books,#Users
```

Comment: 1) isnull в запросе не нужен; 2) чтобы не выводились юзеры с нулевым (или каким-то другим) количеством  - это условие указывается в секции HAVING после GROUP BY

Comment: @DenisRubashkin 1) Да, действительно не нужен. 2) Тогда придется добавлять этот столбец в GROUP BY

Comment: Я не спорю о реализации, а говорю как можно улучшить Ваш ответ. Какой CASE и нулевые значения? Это о чем?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin ам ссори, почему-то решил что это вы написали второй ответ. ISNULL убрал, по HAVING ответил

Comment: В GROUP BY не нужно добавлять, после него добавляем HAVING COUNT(b.idbook) > 0 и вуаля

Comment: @DenisRubashkin хм... ок, добавил и ваш вариант